# Осмысливаем области видимости (Thinking in scopes) Rust

Tags: rust, scope

[В туториале сказано](https://rurust.github.io/rust_book_ru/references-and-borrowing.html#%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-thinking-in-scopes):

Вот код:

```rust
let mut x = 5;
let y = &mut x;

*y += 1;

println!("{}", x);
```

Этот код выдает нам такую ошибку:

```
error: cannot borrow `x` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
    println!("{}", x);
                   ^
```

Это потому, что мы нарушили правила: у нас есть изменяемая ссылка &mut T, указывающая на x, и поэтому мы не можем создать какую-либо &T. Одно из двух. Примечание подсказывает как следует рассматривать эту проблему:

```
note: previous borrow ends here
fn main() {

}
^
```

**Вопрос**

Почему мой код прекрасно компилируется и исполняется?

Мой код:

```rust
#![allow(unused_variables)]
fn main() {
    let mut x = 5;
    let y = &mut x;
    *y += 1;
    println!("{}", x);
}
```

Выход:

```
D:\Source\RUST\playground> cargo build
   Compiling playground v0.1.0 (D:\Source\RUST\playground)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.36s
D:\Source\RUST\playground> cargo run
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.01s
     Running `target\debug\playground.exe`
6
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Эта версия RPL достаточно сильно устарела, актуальную можно найти [здесь](https://doc.rust-lang.ru/book/).

---

Сейчас в Rust *область видимости ссылки* (*reference’s scope*) начинается её объявлением и заканчивается её **последним использованием**. Поэтому в примере всё и в порядке, к моменту `println!` `y` уже вышла из области видимости и *владение* (*ownership*) вернулось к `x`.

Если в `println!`, например, [попробовать](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=35d8d5cc8122cb0713779b6628e68886) распечатать `y`:

```
println!("{} {}", x, y);
```

то увидишь ту же самую ошибку:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `x` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
 --> src/main.rs:5:23
  |
3 |     let y = &mut x;
  |             ------ mutable borrow occurs here
4 |     *y += 1; //
5 |     println!("{} {}", x, y);
  |                       ^  - mutable borrow later used here
  |                       |
  |                       immutable borrow occurs here
```

Comment: Там просто ссылка на старую версию перевода книги. Новая на https://doc.rust-lang.ru/book/ живет.

В https://rust-lang.ru/ ссылки на остальные новые переводы есть.

Comment: @ozkriff, спасибо, поправил.

Comment: Мне кажется, что термин "область видимости" тут и в туториале использован не по назначению. Область именно видимости, т.е. область, где доступно объявленное имя `y`, ограничена окончанием блока `... }`. А вот область жизни переменной-ссылки, к которой можно обратиться по имени `y`, оканчивается после последнего использования. Причем *неявным* образом. Ну и, как все неявное, является постоянным местом для спотыкания.

Comment: @user7860670, согласен, хотел сначала так и написать, но «время жизни ссылок» можно легко спутать с «Lifetime Annotation» и букварь использует тут именно термин «*scope*»… Спорить с ним я не решился… эх… сложно играть в language-lawyer'а для языка без стандарта...